# strerror_r returns trash when I manually set errno during testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, ubuntu, error-handling, mocking

During testing I have a mock object which sets `errno = ETIMEDOUT;`  The object I'm testing sees the error and calls [strerror_r](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get back an error string:

```
if (ret) {
    if (ret == EAI_SYSTEM) {
        char err[128];
        strerror_r(errno, err, 128);
        err_string.assign(err);
    } else {
        err_string.assign(gai_strerror(ret));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I don't understand why `strerror_r` is returning trash.  I even tried calling

```
strerror_r(ETIMEDOUT, err, 128)
```

directly and still got trash.  I must be missing something.  It seems I'm getting the gnu version of the function not the posix one, but that shouldn't make any difference in this case.

**Edit**

I'm on Ubuntu 8.04.  glibc version looks like 2.7 in features.h.

Comment: if you replace strerror_r with perror, what message do you receive?

Comment: `perror` says: Connection timed out.  I put the call immediately before the call to `strerror_r`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this page, http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r, if you're using the GNU version of `strerror_r()`, the function might decide to not store anything at all into the buffer you provide; you'd need to use the string returned from the function (seems like a rather bizarre interface):

> The GNU-specific `strerror_r()` returns a pointer to a string containing the error message. This may be either a pointer to a string that the function stores in buf, or a pointer to some (immutable) static string (in which case buf is unused). If the function stores a string in buf, then at most buflen bytes are stored (the string may be truncated if buflen is too small) and the string always includes a terminating null byte.

So if you happen to be using the GNU version you can't rely on your `err` buffer to have anything useful put into it, unless `strerror_r()` returns the address of `err`.

Comment: So how do I get the xsi / posix version?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Linux has two strerror_r functions. If you read the manual,

```
   int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
               /* XSI-compliant */

   char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
               /* GNU-specific */


The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
       (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE
```

The g++ compiler automatically defines _GNU_SOURCE, so you are using the GNU version of the function which doesn't necessarily store a message in the buffer you provide.

Comment: So how do I get the xsi / posix version?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the g++ compiler from defining _GNU_SOURCE, so you might as well write your program to use that variant.